# Can the google map type be changed to RoadMap when zoomed out?

Tags: google-maps

Google has recently made changes to their maps, it switches to Terrain mode when zoomed out (from zoom level 17 onwards). Is it possible to switch it back or force it to remain in RoadMap mode using the javascript API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do it. Because Google changed tiles itself, so we cannot do it anything.

Answer (score 0):

Kasheftin has come up to a solution to this as an answer to his question "Auto switch to other mapType on max zoom level in google maps": https://stackoverflow.com/a/18147423/348485